# How to remind user when the specific date comes in Watson Conversation Service.or JSON

Tags: json, watson, watson-conversation, reminders

So I am trying to make a reminder chatbot and the code I made is not working as well as I expected.

What I did was, for example, if I were to send a reminder after a day, response conditions would be like the following:

```
"conditions": now().reformatDateTime().toInt()+1
```

then followed by output-text-value as usual.

Is this valid? Any kinds of suggestion will be more than welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You user need to call the day for you get before you did something.
Active your sys entitie: `@sys-date` for get days.

And, for example, user will ask:

- What I need to do today?

Save the day with one context variable, like:

```
{
  "context": {
    "verifiedDate": <? @sys-date ?>;
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Please wait and I'll verified your request."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

And, only if user asks, you will do something within your application for remember the user.

Like:

Example (app.js):

```
function updateMessage(input, data, req, res) {
  if (data.context.verifiedDate){
    searchRequest(data, req, res);
    } else if (data.output && data.output.text) {
      return res.json(data);
    }
    return data;
}
```

You can use the data for sending something within conversation flow.

```
function searchRequest(data, req, res){
    // something to do and return value
    var sendRequest = "Thanks for wait, the request is" + valueRequest;
    data.output.text[0] = sendRequest;
    return data;
}
```

This example is with Nodejs, data have all return from Watson Conversation, like `entities`, `intents`, `context variables`, `node flows`, etc. The logic is the same, you need to access the data returned from your conversation, and after, access the `context variables` to do something within your app.

Add days:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

var dat = new Date();

alert(dat.addDays(5))
```

You can add days with the days parameter or with one number, like my example.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply., But what I actually want is, let say I am making a food expiry reminder chatbot, so if the user just write "milk" down, the chatbot would remind you after 14 days, which is the average due date of milk. So my questions come down to this. 1, is @sys-date considered prerequisite to make a reminder in chat bot 2. and is it possible to recall expected due date for each product, like milk - 14 days and cheeze -7 days in JSON. i am not sure if that was clear :'( Thanks

Comment: in this case, where the dates is saved? have some database? Or in this case is static for everything? Like: Milk always have - 14days, cheese -7 days?

Comment: They are static for everything, the only problem I face now is how should I access system-date and starts counting afterward til the due date ends..;'(

Comment: You will need to access the sys-date, save with one context variable, and use my code within my edit to add the days with your application.